# Custom currency format

Tags: java, strings, formatting

I have the following code for currency formatting

```
boolean isNegative = probe.nl_price!=null && probe.nl_price.signum() == -1;
String str = "Price: " + (isNegative ? "-" :"") + "$" + FormatUtils.getFormatInstance().format(probe.nlr_price.abs())
```

Is there more elgant way to rewrite it?

Comment: Can you provide also the probe class together with the `nl_price` and `nlr_price` with some explication?  It's also strange that you don't use the getters for last 2 classes but acces the variable directly. 
I have a feeling that we can refactor there so this can be better.

Comment: If `probe.nl_price` is `null`, a `NullPointerException` will be thrown at `probe.nlr_price.abs()`. So checking for it before for the sign is useless.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an optional if you are using java 8. It would be nice to have all the code though.

```
 String sign = Optional.ofNullable(probe.nl_price)
                             .filter(p -> p.signsum() == -1)
                             .map(p -> "-")
                             .orElse("");
```